# Can you Eldritch Blast as a Readied action even though it's multiple attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, readied-action

It has been already said that [the eldritch blast is an attack with separate spell attack rolls on each beam](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49150/eldritch-blast-with-multiple-beams-and-agonizing-blast-on-a-single-target-cha-m)

The PHB states:

> You can direct the beams at the same target or at different ones. Make
>   a separate attack roll for each beam.

**But what happens when you ready an action with an eldritch blast?** You can't do multiple attacks on a readied action, I can't find any rules that contradicts that the eldritch blast can be used at its full potential on a readied action.

Comment: Question: Are you asking how to ready multiple targets with eldritch blast, or whether or not you can because it has multiple targets?

Comment: Probably both, like for example. "I'm going to ready an action and precast an eldritch blast, the trigger is going to be a moving goblin". When the triggers happens he can shoot 3 eldritch blast rays, no matter the target.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Ready action includes no restrictions on the number of attacks you can make. You might be thinking of the restriction in the Extra Attack ability:

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of
>   once, whenever you take the Attack action **on your turn**.

So a character with Extra Attack can only make a single attack when they Ready the Attack action, but there is no general restriction on multiple attacks with the Ready Action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30990/discussion-between-lino-frank-ciaralli-and-miniman).

Answer (score 8):

For the Action on your turn in the round, you take the Ready Action (PHB 193), establishing a trigger for which you will Cast A Spell, Eldritch Blast. When the triggering situation you specified occurs, you use your reaction to cast Eldritch Blast, which counts as a single action. Eldritch Blast, or its friend Scorching Ray, have you make an attack roll for each sub element of the spell. You are still only making one action, it is just that each component of that action requires its own roll to determine if it hits.

Caution: per the RAW, Readying a spell requires Concentration (PHB 203), an expensive resource for a Warlock. You can only Concentrate on one thing at a time and you risk losing the spell if you take damage (CON save with a difficulty check of 10 or half the damage, which ever is greater). Weigh readying Eldritch Blast against the many Warlock spells requiring Concentration.

Comment: Luckily Eldritch Blast is a cantrip and uses no spell slots, so at least that resource isn't being wasted should they be interrupted.

Comment: Agreed @Airatome; Eldritch blast is a wonderful thing. I brought up the risk because in playing my Lock I nearly stumbled into the trap while concentrating on Hunger of Hadar. With Repelling blast, you can throw an emerging thing back in, yet readying it causes you to lose concentration on Hunger of Hadar.

Comment: Ahhh I see your point.  Even Readying a cantrip requires you to Concentrate until the trigger happens, meaning you give up concentration on anything else that came before.  Tricky...

Comment: Ah. It still reads like your citing the full "readying a spell requires concentration..." which is on page 193. But I understand your intent now that you explain it.