# Is moving between separate attacks of the same spell unbalanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, movement, house-rules

As stated in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169144/can-you-move-between-the-separate-attacks-of-a-spell), you can't move between attacks when casting spells like *Eldritch Blast* as per RAW.

My question is, if a GM would allow this to happen (cast a beam to a creature, move, and then cast the second beam at the same creature) invoking RAI or just because he feels like it, would that unbalance the game in any way?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Related (this change *does* have an effect): "[When are targets picked for spells with multiple "missiles"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51722)" and somewhat related (a possible use-case): "[Do multiple hits of Repelling Blast happen simultaneously or in succession?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93419)

Comment: Given that this would be a house rule, how would you want this to interact with the Sorcerer's Twinned Spell Metamagic option? Can they select their second target after moving after the first attack? Or would they have to select both targets at the same time but could move between the attacks?

Comment: A small thing: are you asking whether this change does anything at all (changes the game) or if the change creates alarming alterations to the game's balance?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Depending on your definition of 'balanced'

Using a house rule or breaking from RAW in this instance increases the flexibility of the attack [ for example staggering Eldritch Blast attacks]. This increases how powerful spell attacks of this form are because it allows the caster to do things they normally could not.

Say on a given attack the caster can only see one target and kills them with a fraction of the spells capability - but if they could move during the spell cast they could attack more than one target thus preserving all of the potential damage output of the spell.

hypothetical anecdotes like the one I listed above are the reason why the house rule you're describing 'unbalances' or increases the power of 'multi-attack' spells like Eldritch Blast.

That being said - how much more powerful the spell becomes from this house rule depends highly on the encounters that your PC caster experiences and is extremely difficult to say if the house rule is 'broken' or 'overpowered'. Typically this change in spell mechanics would be advantageous but not game breaking.

Comment: I don't believe this question was asking whether this change alters the power of things *in general*, but instead was asking whether the change resulted in *unreasonable* increases in power

Comment: 'unreasonable' is an extremely subjective word.

Comment: Yes and answers should support *why* they feel the change is unreasonable or entirely overpowered. I've asked the OP what they are expecting from answers

Answer (score 2):

### It works OK for martial combatants, so probably OK for casters

A martial combatant with extra attack can fire a bow, then move, then fire the bow again. This doesn't overpower combat. From this point of view, allowing casters to move between beams would not break anything.

But...

### Moving between beams creates "interesting" situations with *counterspell*

Imagine a warlock, Ára, who can see one foe, Tinco, but is in total cover from a second foe, Parma. Ára casts *eldritch blast*, sending one beam at Tinco and killing them. Ára then moves out of total cover to attack Parma, at which point in time Parma casts *counterspell*. What happens?

Does Parma's *counterspell* retroactively cancel Tinco's death? If not, that depowers *counterspell*. If it does, then the people at the table have more work as they "undo" damage and other effects. Rewinding time is a hassle.

If you don't allow *counterspell* at all in this situation, deciding that it must be cast when the mage is first casting the spell, then spellcasters become extremely powerful. Imagine Ára casting *fireball* while behind concealment (safe from counterspelling) then moving into view and releasing the fireball.

### Concentration

Additionally, is Ára considered to be concentrating during the move? If they take damage while moving (from a reaction attack, for example) do they have to make a concentration save? If it fails, does that change Tinco's death?

### Decide early

These questions need to be answered at the table before the situation comes up at the table.

Comment: "Imagine Ára casting fireball while behind concealment (safe from counterspelling) then moving into view and releasing the fireball." except this isn't possible because *fireball* does not involve multiple attacks. I'm fairly certain this change only affects *eldritch blast*, *scorching ray* and *maybe* *steel wind strike*. Also it *is* possible to Ready a spell while behind total cover, and then move out from the cover and fire the spell, though this uses your reaction as well